# Atlas creator of collada models

Tags: 3d, collada

Hi does anyone know some software (preferably script), which can do atlas from textures and recalculate the coordinates for models in the COLLADA format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote one for [meshtool](https://github.com/pycollada/meshtool). You can use it like this:

```
meshtool --load_collada file.dae --medium_optimizations --make_atlases \
         --save_collada_zip out.zip
```

If that doesn't create a full atlas, you might want to also try passing `--adjust_texcoords` before the `--make_atlases`.

Comment: thanks it works for me with --adjust_texcoords param, sometimes it left one or more textures and not join them to atlas, but for now is enough for me;-)

Comment: If it left them out, there was probably a good reason. The texcoords probably wrapped the texture multiple times